# Excel formula: link to another file, substitute file's name with cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have 1 excel file for accumulating data and 100 files with data. Each file of those 100 is named `1.xls`, `2.xls`... I have a column in my first excel file with file names: 1, 2... In the second column I get data from each corresponding data file: `='[1.xls]1'!A1`, `='[2.xls]1'!A1`...

However, I need to type in the file's name in those formulas manually or to open the file and select the `A1` cell. Is there any way I can automate it through excel formulas, so that the file's name in the formula depended on the value in the first column?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `INDIRECT` function. Formula for B1 (not tested):

```
=INDIRECT("'[" & A1 & ".xls]1'!A1")
```

According to [manual](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB), all referenced workbooks have to be open.